# Setting up mime_types.rb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I am trying to use Prawn in RoR 4.2.0. I am trying to add the following to my mime_types file:

```
Mime::Type.register “application/pdf” , :pdf
```

However, the server does not start with the following error:

```
/Users/Bob/Development/appname/config/initializers/mime_types.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `“application' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's probably the curly quotes here: `“application/pdf”`.  Perhaps `"application/pdf"` instead?

Comment: yep, thanks!!, how to give you points?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the curly quotes in `“application/pdf”` with straight quotes (i.e. `"application/pdf"`)

Comment: Worked for me.
Thanks for sharing.